# SwiftUI - Return values from array of structs are all in one row

Tags: arrays, swift, sqlite, struct, swiftui

I am calling a function in order to do a select statement in a bundled SQLite database. The function returns an array of structs. The database is being read correctly as I have put some print commands in the code. However the final array only has 1 row in it, which contains all the data, instead of 16 rows of structs.

The struct code, which is in databaseHelper.swift, is...

```
struct ButtonData: Hashable {
    let english: String
    let categoryID: Int
    let indonesian: String
}
```

The database code, in databaseHelper, is

```
class DatabaseHelper {

    var buttonVars = [ButtonData]()

    var database: Connection!

    let buttonsTable = Table("Button")
    let english = Expression<String>("english")
    let category = Expression<String>("category")
    let categoryID = Expression<Int>("ID")
    let filename = Expression<String>("filename")
    let indonesian = Expression<String>("indonesian")

    init() {

        do {
            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sga", ofType: "db")!
            let database = try Connection(path, readonly: true)
            self.database = database
            print("Database initialized at path \(path)")
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }


    func queryDatabase(passedCategory: String) -> [ButtonData] {

        do {
            let buttons = try self.database.prepare(self.buttonsTable.filter(self.category==passedCategory))
            for row in buttons {
                print("English: \(row[self.english]), ID: \(row[self.categoryID]), Indonesian: \(row[self.indonesian])")
            //    buttonVars.append(ButtonData(english: row[english], categoryID: row[categoryID], indonesian: row[indonesian]))
                buttonVars.append(ButtonData(english: row[english], categoryID: row[categoryID], indonesian: row[indonesian]))
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        print(buttonVars[0])
        print(buttonVars[1])
        print(buttonVars[2])
        print(buttonVars[3])
        print(buttonVars[4])
        print(buttonVars[5])
        print(buttonVars[6])
        print(buttonVars[7])
        print(buttonVars[8])
        print(buttonVars[9])
        print(buttonVars[10])
        print(buttonVars[11])
        print(buttonVars[12])
        print(buttonVars[13])
        print(buttonVars[14])
        print(buttonVars[15])
        return buttonVars
    }
}
```

The function code, which is in SoundPageView.swift (this page calls the database function), is...

```
    func getArrayValues() {
        let buttonRows = [DatabaseHelper().queryDatabase(passedCategory: category)]
        let btnCount: Int = buttonRows.count
        print(btnCount)
        print(buttonRows[0])
    }
```

The print values in the console show me that btnCount = 1 but before the array is returned, it is made of 16 rows. It is only after it is returned that it is reduced to 1 row.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I don't know how to access the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are putting the brackets in this call:

```
let buttonRows = [DatabaseHelper().queryDatabase(passedCategory: category)]
```

The func queryDatabase returns an array on its own.  I think it should be this:

```
let buttonRows = DatabaseHelper().queryDatabase(passedCategory: category)
```

Otherwise your result will be an array with one entry, which is the result of the call to queryDatabase.

Comment: Yes that was it, you saved me again Hal! Thanks again!